# HTML JS trigger button enter

Tags: javascript, html, button, triggers

Was trying to get this working that I saw from another post here. I got it working but I can get the enter to work. I tried to tie in https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_trigger_button_enter but for the life of me cant get both to work.

Hope someone can help!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#button').click(function(e) {  
        var inputvalue = $("#input").val();
        window.location.replace(" http://www.example.com/page/"+inputvalue);

    });
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>

       <input type="text" value="11" id="input"> 
       <button type="button" id="button">Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Want to have it where on a website a user can enter a zip code. Then when they do that and hit the enter key or hit the button to enter it will take them to a website page that is the zip code they enter. The code I put above works for what I want done. But It doesn’t work with enter key on phone or desktop.

Answer (score 1):

just use the keypress event handler from jquery on the document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(this).keypress(function(event) {
        if(event.which == 13) {
            updateValue();
        }
    });

    $('#button').click(function(e) {  
        updateValue();
    });

    function updateValue() {
        var inputvalue = $("#input").val();
        window.location.replace(" http://www.example.com/page/"+inputvalue);
    };
});
</script>
```

Comment: Okay, I have tried to add that to that code above and I just can't figure out what to put in place of the alert you have there to make it go to the link with the input value.

Comment: Wouldn't it have to be a keyup instead of keypress?

Comment: Just replace the alert sentence by the lines of code in the example you provided.

Comment: Can you attach the code here? Can’t get it to function correctly, it’s one or the other that works I can’t get both working